# How to make an electronic switch for a current-mode digital to analog converter?

Tags: digital-logic, analog, dac, switching-regulator, analog-switch

In a current-mode DAC there is a switch in the current path between virtual ground and actual ground based on width.

[image]

How can I design the switch used?

Comment: You can use an analogue switch.

Comment: Start with a specification, then select switching elements that can meet that specification.